# PHP unable to find libraries using Cpanel

Tags: php, cpanel, whm

I have recently had to migrate to a brand new server after a sudden server crash. I am now getting an error where if I email a certain email address, (which I know i pipe to a `PHP` script), i get the following error message back via email:

`This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.`

A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:

`pipe to |/home/username/public_html/support/api/pipe.php`
    generated by email

The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ `pipe to |/home/username/public_html/support/api/pipe.php`
       generated by email------

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/msql.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/msql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/cpanel/ea-php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so' - /opt/cpanel/ea-php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

What is strange is I have the extensions installed via `EasyApache`. But if I do an ls on this, i only get the following:

```
[root@bob home]# ls /opt/cpanel/ea-php54/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/
ctype.so  imap.so            mysqlnd.so      phar.so       sqlite3.so    xml.so
curl.so   json.so            pdo_mysqlnd.so  posix.so      tokenizer.so  xmlwriter.so
dom.so    mysqlnd_mysqli.so  pdo.so          simplexml.so  wddx.so       xsl.so
ftp.so    mysqlnd_mysql.so   pdo_sqlite.so   sockets.so    xmlreader.so
```

Comment: **msql** doesn't seem right?

Comment: I thought it was a bit strange, but its obviously calling it from somewhere.